# IntelliSense: no operator "<<" matches these operands

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm getting the error:

```
 IntelliSense: no operator "<<" matches these operands
 operand types are: std::ostream << std::string c:\Users\mohammad\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\summing a list of number\summing a list of number\summing a list of number.cpp  10
```

Here is the code:

```
 // summing a list of number.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
int sum(int a[], int from, int size, const string& context, int depth)
{
    string indent(depth, '|');
    cout << indent << context << "(a, " << from << ", " << size << ")" << endl;
    int result = 0;
    if (size == 1)
    {
        result = a[from];
    }
    else if (size > 1)
    {
        int midpoint = size / 2;
        int left = sum(a, from, midpoint, "left", depth + 1);
        int right = sum(a, from + midpoint, size - midpoint, "right", depth + 1);
        result = left + right;
        cout << indent << "=" << left << "+" << right << endl;
    }
    cout << indent << "=" << result << endl;
    return result;
}

int main(){
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    cout << "sum = " << sum(a, 0, 10, "sum", 0) << endl;
    getchar();
}
```

Why does it say there is an error due to std and ostream, when I already have included iostream and std?

I'm using VS-2013.

Comment: If you split up the output statement into multiple lines, with one output per line it will be easier to see which of the outputs IntelliSense complains about. Also note that the parser used by IntelliSense is not the same as the parser used by the compiler, so you might get false positives from IntelliSense.

Comment: (Not used VC++, so I might be wrong.) Shouldn't the standard includes be done with `<` and `>` instead of `"` and `"`?

Comment: @GáborBakos The preprocessor will look at the local directory of the source file first, and if the header file is not found will go to search the standard include paths.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

by changing this line:

```
#include "iostream"
```

into

```
#include <iostream>
```

and adding srings as:

```
#include <string>
```

it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Add to your include region a new line with following:
`#include "string"`. 
IntelliSense and even your build system do not know what this string type objects are. You should include the above mentioned header (which is the declaration) for the type string from std to let both know what it is and what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

you should also include string library like this i.e  `#include <string>` and change from #include "iostream" to `#include <iostream>`